# Java Comparing each element in a row to all elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array and I'm trying to step through the array such that for the first row, I'd like to step through each element and compare them to all the other elements in the row to check some conditions I am interested in. Then move on to the next row, do the same, and repeat until I step through whole array. The conditions I am interested in are within my if/else blocks.

Here is my sample 2D array:

```
int [][] a = { {4,16,5}, {1,12,1}, {8,9,13}, {3,4,7}};
```

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayElementComparison {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // define the test array

    int [][] a = { {4,16,5}, {1,12,1}, {8,9,13}, {3,4,7}};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < a.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("a[i][k-1] " + a[i][k-1]);


            if (a[i][k-1] == 4) 
            {
                if (a[i][k] == 16)
                {
                    System.out.println("4->16");
                }
            }
            else if (a[i][k-1] == 12)
            {
                if (a[i][k] == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("12->1");
                }
            }
            else if (a[i][k-1] == 9)
            {
                if (a[i][k] == 13)
                {
                    System.out.println("9->13");
                }
            }
            else if (a[i][k-1] == 3)
            {
                if (a[i][k] == 7)
                {
                    System.out.println("3->7");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Here is the output:

```
a[i][k-1] 4
4->16
a[i][k-1] 16
a[i][k-1] 5
a[i][k-1] 1
a[i][k-1] 12
12->1
a[i][k-1] 1
a[i][k-1] 8
a[i][k-1] 9
9->13
a[i][k-1] 13
a[i][k-1] 3
a[i][k-1] 4
a[i][k-1] 7
```

From the output, it is apparent that it is capturing the first 3 conditions, but not the fourth one (3->7). I realize this is because it is only checking the element that is the next adjacent one to the current. However, I don;t know how to fix the code so that it checks the whole row, and not only the next adjacent one.

Comment: You need to add an inner loop around your conditions which replaces `-1` with `-n`, where `n` is the number of elements to look back.

Comment: Just for me to understand your issue... do you need to compare 4 with 16 and 5, then to compare 16 with 5 and then to do the same in the next rows?

Comment: @brlaranjeira Yes. you are correct. But it appears the solution was already posted. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate within each subarray. Try this out:

```
int[][] a = { { 4, 16, 5 }, { 1, 12, 1 }, { 8, 9, 13 }, { 3, 4, 7 } };

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int[] inner = a[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < inner.length; k++) {
        int current = inner[k]; // current value being compared

        // copy the remaining items in the array to a new array for iterating 
        int[] subInner = Arrays.copyOfRange(inner, k + 1, inner.length);

        for (int n = 0; n < subInner.length; n++) {
            int comparedTo = subInner[n]; // current value that "current" is comparing itself to
            System.out.println("array " + (i + 1) + " compare " + current + " to " + comparedTo);

            if (current == 4 && comparedTo == 16) {
                System.out.println("4->16");
            } else if (current == 12 && comparedTo == 1) {
                System.out.println("12->1");
            } else if (current == 9 && comparedTo == 13) {
                System.out.println("9->13");
            } else if (current == 3 && comparedTo == 7) {
                System.out.println("3->7");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was really neat! Thanks for your help @CDelaney. Thanks everyone else as well.

Comment: You can avoid creating a copy of the array (`subInner`) by running the inner most loop in the `inner` array, with `for (int n = k + 1; n < inner.length; n++) `. Use  `compareTo = inner[n]` for the second value.

Comment: The second loop should say: `for (int k = 0; k < inner.length-1; k++) {`. It only needs to run to the second to last item, as it then has one remaining item to compare with. _(The original code will also work, however will do an extra loop with an empty 'subInner' array.)_

Comment: @UdoBorkowski Agreed on both accounts. I chose readability to make it very clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need another level of nested loops.

Your first loop can remain unchanged; it loops through the rows.

Your second loop needs to loop through all of the positions in the row for the left side of the comparison, and a new third loop needs to loop through all of the remaining positions in the row for the right side of the comparison.

```
for (int k = 0; i < a[i].length - 1; k++) { // Modified second loop
    for (int j = k + 1; j < a[i].length; ++) { // Examine remaining elements in the row

        if (a[i][k] == 4 && a[i][j] == 16) {
            System.out.println("4->16");
        // Construct remaining "else if" conditions similarly.
```

This will catch any pair of elements in the same row that fit your values.

Answer (score 0):

To look back through all elements in the row, you'd need to add a further inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 1; k < a.length; k++) {
        System.out.println("a[i][k-1] " + a[i][k-1]);
        for (int n = 1; n <= k; ++n) {
          if (a[i][k-n] == 4) 
          {
              if (a[i][k] == 16) 
              // ...
          } else if ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion and I am getting the following error:

a[i][k-1] 4
4->16
a[i][k-1] 16
a[i][k-1] 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at ArrayElementComparison.main(ArrayElementComparison.java:20)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have two nested loops to check if the two numbers exist in one row.

In the following code the function `contains` does this job. With your example of a 3 numbers row it will compare the items at the indices `0,1`, `0,2`, `1,2`.

Your modified code looks like this:

```
public class ArrayElementComparison {

    public static boolean contains(int[] a, int n1, int n2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] == n1) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (a[j] == n2) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // define the test array
        int[][] a = {{4, 16, 5}, {1, 12, 1}, {8, 9, 13}, {3, 4, 7}};

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int[] row = a[i];
            printRow(row);
            if (contains(row, 4, 16)) {
                System.out.println("4->16");
            } else if (contains(a[i], 12, 1)) {
                System.out.println("12->1");
            } else if (contains(a[i], 9, 13)) {
                System.out.println("9->13");
            } else if (contains(a[i], 3, 7)) {
                System.out.println("3->7");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printRow(int[] row) {
        for (int i : row) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```